# Scatterplot in Shiny

Tags: r, ggplot2, shiny, rstudio, scatter-plot

I am trying to create a scatterplot based on a csv I have loaded however when I run the code I either get no plot showing or an error when I include the aes mapping: "Mapping should be created with `aes()` or `aes_()`."

Can anyone give me pointers on where I am going wrong?

Code:

```
library(shiny)
library(ggplot2)

ui <- (fluidPage(
titlePanel("Pig Breeds"),
sidebarLayout(
sidebarPanel(
  selectInput(inputId = "x", 
              label = "Pig Breeds:", 
              choices = c("total_pigs", "female_breeding_herd", 
                          "in_pig_sows", "in_pig_gifts", "other_sows", 
                          "maiden_gilts", "boars_for_service", "other_pigs"),
              selected = "total_pigs"),
  selectInput(inputId = "y",
              label = "Year by year change:",
              choices = c(2016, 2017, 2018, "year_on_year_change"),
              selected = 2016),
  actionButton(inputId = "update", label = "update")
            ),
mainPanel = (
  plotOutput(outputId = "scatterplot")
  )
)
)
)

server <- (function(input, output) {
output$scatterplot <- renderPlot({
ggplot(data=(read.csv("eu_pigs.csv")),
            aes(x = output$x, y = output$y) + 
            geom_point())
observeEvent(input$update, {print(as.numeric(input$update))})
       }
    )
  }
 )

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the error message says, you’re using `aes` incorrectly. The function takes *column names*, not variable references. That is, replace

```
aes(x = output$x, y = output$y)
```

by

```
aes(x = x, y = y)
```

Or, more likely you want to be able to control the plot from the inputs, so you’d want to use

```
aes_string(x = input$x, y = input$y)
```

There are also quite a few stray parentheses and braces in your code. Remove those. Furthermore, `mainPanel` is a **function** that you need to call. Your code is instead assigning something to it.

And lastly, you actually need to *plot* your plot. After all these things are fixed, the relevant code looks like this:

```r
ui <- fluidPage(
    titlePanel("Pig Breeds"),
    sidebarLayout(
        sidebarPanel(…),
        mainPanel(
            plotOutput(outputId = "scatterplot")
        )
    )
)

server <- function(input, output) {
    output$scatterplot <- renderPlot({
        p = ggplot(data = read.csv("eu_pigs.csv")) +
            aes_string(x = input$x, y = input$y) +
            geom_point()
        plot(p)
        observeEvent(input$update, print(as.numeric(input$update)))
    })
}
```

*If* the plot object is the last thing you are executing in the `renderPlot` function, you can omit `plot`:

```
output$scatterplot <- renderPlot({
    ggplot(data = read.csv("eu_pigs.csv")) +
        aes_string(x = input$x, y = input$y) +
        geom_point()
})
```

Comment: amended the aes and removed the extra braces etc in my code but when I run the app the main panel is blank... am I missing something?

Comment: perfect! thank you for helping me with this... still very new to shiny and gig-lot so at least I understand where I have went wrong and can avoid this in the future.